# Can I see my current billing so far this month? (Firebase Blaze Plan)

Tags: firebase

I just updated to firebase Blaze plan (pay as you go) and I wonder if there's a way to check how many usd am I getting charged so far this month.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the [usage and billing](https://firebase.corp.google.com/project/_/usage) page of your project in the Firebase console, you can see the running cost for your project in this billing cycle.

This is what it looks like for one of my projects:
[image: usage and billing console showing $1.36 running cost]

To get to this, either click the link above, or:

1. Go to firebase.google.com/console
2. Select your project.
3. Click the settings icon to the right of the <kbd>Project Overview</kbd> link
4. Select <kbd>Usage and billing</kbd>